# How to document an array with subarrays (mixed type)?

Tags: php, arrays, documentation-generation

To document a variable that can take an array that receives a vector whose values ​​are strings:

```
/*
 * @var string[] An array of string objects.
 */
$foo = array('A', 'B', 'C');
```

To document a variable that can take an array that receives a vector whose values ​​are integer:

```
/*
 * @var int[] An array of string objects.
 */
$foo = array(1, 5, 0);
```

how should I document a variable whose values ​​are mixed arrays?

I need document a array like this:

```
$foo = array(
    array('value A',  1, $this),
    array('value b',  2, NULL),
    array('value X', 15, new Test)
);
```

I imagine it's something like this:

```
/*
 * @var array[][string|int|object|null] Description.
 */
```

Comment: @var array[] An array of mixed objects.

Comment: `@var mixed[] An array of mixed objects`.

Comment: "mixed indicates that a parameter may accept multiple (but not necessarily all) types." (http://php.net/manual/de/language.pseudo-types.php) - properly speaking this doesn't apply here, because the inner values are all arrays and not mixed.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [current draft](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) of PHPDoc (FIG PSR-5 applicant), the @var tag is [deprecated](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#824-var-deprecated). They suggest using an [@type tag](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#822-type) instead.

The type of variable is still an array; the contents of that array would be be briefly mentioned in the description.

```
/**
 * @var array $foo An array of string elements.
 */
```

or

```
/**
 * @type array $foo An array of string elements.
 */
```

If the variable might contain things other than strings, I might say `An array of mixed elements.`, or if I knew specifically what they might be `An array of bool|string|object elements.`

If the variable itself might be of various types, I would give the list of types it might be.

```
/**
 * @type bool|string|array $foo Mixed type, depending on result of baz().
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, Maybe `@type \ArrayObject<\ArrayObject<string, integer, object>>`?

Comment: No. PHP's variables have a [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php "PHP.net"). An array is an array **type**. An array has elements. An instance of a class is an object **type**, and it may have properties. So `@type array $nameOfVariable Description of variable` When describing the variable's contents, be brief. Use the pipe symbol ('|') to separate **types**, because the contents may be "this OR that" **type**. In documentation it is very important to avoid confusion, so do not use the word 'object' when you mean 'element'.

Comment: A sub-array should be documented where it is generated. It does not need to be documented where it is an element. It may be documented in the description, for example `@type array $variable Holds arrays generated by Classname::arrayGeneratingMethod()`